# Checking if a variable has one of several possible values

Tags: autohotkey

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
IfNotEqual, A_OSVersion = WIN_7, WIN_VISTA, WIN_XP
{
   MsgBox, This script is only supported on Windows XP, Vista, or 7.
   Exit
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do and double check the formatting?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you clarified the situtation.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you trying to do? What have you looked up and found so far? These are things that are normally expected when you ask for help like this. The lack of these is why I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want :
based on (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm)

```
if A_OSVersion not in WIN_7,WIN_VISTA,WIN_XP
{
    MsgBox This Script is only supported on Windows XP, Vista or 7
    ExitApp
}
```

Comment: What's sad is I didn't even know this autohotkey thing existed until today. I simply googled it, went to the documentation and it was practically on the first page..